# Être atterri VS Avoir atterri

Tags: conjugaison, auxiliaires

Quelle est la différence d'usage entre les deux auxiliaires utilisés pour ce verbe?

Selon moi, on utilise *avoir atterri* pour les passagers d'un avion par exemple et *être atterri* pour le pilote qui a réalisé l'action ou un oiseau.

[Cnrtl : atterrir](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/atterrir) dont je n'ai pas compris la mention

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pour le pilote aussi, ainsi que pour les oiseaux, on dit *avoir atterri*.

L'exemple de CNRTL que vous référencez est un homophone qui n'a rien à voir avec les avions, mais avec des mouvements de terre (càd, comme dans les travaux publics).

Pour reprendre un exemple dans [ATTERRIR<sup>2</sup>](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/atterrir), qui montre bien que *avoir* est utilisé pour conjuguer cet *atterrir*:

> Je raconterai une courte escale quelque part dans le monde. C'était près de Concordia, en Argentine, mais c'eût pu être partout ailleurs : le mystère est ainsi répandu. ***J'avais atterri*** dans un champ, ... Saint-Exupéry, Terre des hommes,1939, p. 180.

Donc, même si l'avion et le pilote sont au sol, et ont fini *d'atterrir*, on utilise l'auxiliaire *avoir* pour conjuguer *atterrir*. On ne dit pas:

> <strike>Je suis atterri.</strike>

[ATTERRIR<sup>1</sup>](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/atterrir), qui a un tout autre sens, se conjugue normalement avec le verbe *avoir* ***mais*** avec le verbe *être* pour parler du résultat de l'action:

> Ces barrages ***furent*** promptement ***atterris***, et les dépôts retenus à leur amont furent plantés en feuillus de toute sorte. Reboisement des montagnes, compte-rendu, 1869-74, 2efasc., p. 20 (Littré Suppl. 1877).

le sens étant ici: *Obstruer, remplir de terre*. Ce sens du verbe atterrir est marqué rare.

Comment: Oui -- c'est-à-dire que "*être* atterri" n'est que la forme transitive du verbe à la voix passive (principe qui s'appliquera à de nombreux cas).