# Si l'on avait dit à nos arrière-grands-pères qu'on serait atteris sur la Lune, ils ne l'auraient pas cru

Tags: temps-grammatical

Si l'on avait dit à nos arrière-grands-pères qu'on serait atteris sur la Lune, ils ne l'auraient pas cru.

**serait atteris**
Je ne comprends pas cette construction.

Answer (score 2):

Une raison pour laquelle tu ne la comprends pas est probablement le fait qu'elle est incorrecte.

Atterrir [s'utilise avec l'auxiliaire ***avoir***](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/24679/%C3%8Atre-atterri-vs-avoir-atterri) mais ici, on utilisera soit le semi-auxiliaire ***aller***, soit le conditionnel.

> Si l'on avait dit à nos arrière-grands-pères qu'on **allait** atte**rr**ir sur la Lune, ils ne l'auraient pas cru.
>
> Si l'on avait dit à nos arrière-grands-pères qu'on atte**rrirait** (un jour) sur la Lune, ils ne l'auraient pas cru.

Comment: Non seulement c'est plus adapté, mais c'est **la** solution correcte. Il s'agit ici d'exprimer un futur proche dans la passé, ce qui se construit avec **aller (à l'imparfait) + infinitif**. La seule autre alternative serait d'utiliser le conditionnel : *Si l'on avait dit à nos arrière-grands-pères qu'on atterrirait sur la Lune, ils ne l'auraient pas cru.* Car au moment où la phrase était hypothétiquement prononcée, elle était encore incertaine.

Comment: @Sharcoux Le conditionnel passé surcomposé nous offre peut-être une « autre autre alternative » (n'ayons pas peur des pléonasmes et autres anglicismes) : *Si l'on avait dit à nos arrière-grands-pères qu'on aurait eu atterri sur la Lune, ils ne l'auraient pas cru* ;-)

Comment: Je ne suis pas certain à 100% de ce que je vais dire, mais cette forme signifierait que l'atterrissage sur la lune aurait précédé le doute des aïeux, ce qui n'a aucun sens. Après vérification, j'ai trouvé : *On emploie un temps surcomposé lorsque l’on mentionne un fait ayant eu lieu immédiatement avant celui dont au parle au temps composé correspondant*, ce qui confirmerait plutôt mon intuition. Dans tous les cas, j'aurais du mal à encourager l'usage de cette forme à un apprenant...

Comment: @Sharcoux Oui. C'était une blague. Quand j'ai écrit le semi-auxiliaire aller est plus adapté, je ne voulais pas dire qu'avoir l'était aussi. Je réécrit cette partie.